# How do I mimic the Chrome debugger to delete cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to delete cookies for a particular URL. If I go to 'Application' on the Chrome debugger I see storage including Cookies on the left. If I right click on the URL and select 'Clear' all the cookies dissapear for that URL. So I have two questions. One how do I delete cookies like the Chrome debugger using JavaScript. I have seen many posts that indicate I need to supply the path and domain to successfully delete a cookie. Somehow the debugger queries for the Path and Domain (along with other characteristics and removes the cookies associated with the URL. Two I notice that the Chrome debugger also maintains a list of URLs (sites I guess) that have cookies. How is this list formed?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a massive security flaw if you could access this information via JS from an arbitrary application. You can only manipulate cookies in the same domain where your application is running from.

To answer your question, the browser has management abilities over the cookies because it's obviously what stores them, applications don't have access to all browser cookies. Also, there's no way to delete a cookie per se via JS, all you can do is expire it and let the browser get it cleaned up.

Comment: With Chrome under Applications and under 'Cookies' I see the cookies groups by URL. As I stated right clicking on the URL listed and selecting 'Clear' clears the cookies. It probably does as you say expire actually delete them. Also since the browser is storing the cooies it might have access to all the attributes. Particullarly 'path' and 'domain'. I was just hoping that there was an API other than directly manipulating the cookie string to to get at the 'path', 'domain', 'age', etc. Also that this was a JS API to group the cookies by URL like the Chrome browser by URL.